# On use of C++ singleton class

Tags: c++, singleton

I have looked at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86582/singleton-how-should-it-be-used) on singleton class implementation, but not clear on how to use it in practice. To make the context more concrete, say I have a input stream `std::istream` instance that many different class need to access, but instead of passing it in for each class constructor, I am thinking of using a singleton class `Connection` to wrap this info. So a client can just call:

```
Connection.getInstance().get_input_stream();
```

My questions are two fold: (1) is this a proper use of singleton class (2) on implementing this, I have tried something like this:

```
class Connection {
public:
    static Connection& getInstance() {
        static Connection instance; // Guaranteed to be destroyed   
        return instance;
    }
    std::istream& get_istream() {
        return is;
    }

    void set_istream(std::istream & stream) {
            is = stream;
    }
private:
    std::istream& is;
}
```

First this code doesn't compile for some reason. Second it feels awkward that you have to call `set_istream()` before it is usable. Is there a better way to get this done? Thanks.

EDIT: Apparently, trying to assign a reference is my silly doing, as many of you pointed out. The second part is how to pass in `stream` information into singleton - it seems not worth it, which suggests this might be a wrong case for using it. thanks you all for your answers.

Comment: It doesn't compile because you're trying to assign to a reference variable. You can only initialize it in constructor's initializer list.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is so bad about Singletons?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons)

Comment: Also to use it you need to use the static method accessor like Connection::getInstance().get_input_stream();

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Though very relevant, not even close to duplicate.

Comment: @MooingDuck: It answers the first question; the remaining questions are only relevant if the OP decides to ignore it.

Comment: Look at This also!!
http://stackoverflow.com/q/8906817/1155650

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A reference can't be modified after creation, so to "set" the istream, you'd have to pass it to the ctor:

```
class Connection {

    /* ... */

    Connection(std::istream & stream) : is(stream) {}
private:
    std::istream& is;
}
```

That raises a problem, however, of how you pass the correct stream to the ctor when you're creating a static instance -- and the answer to that is that it's non-trivial (at best). You could use a pointer instead of a reference, so you can create an object and point it at an actual stream later, but at that point you're basically asking for trouble (requiring two-stage initialization).

Ultimately, it's just not worth it. My advice would be against using singleton in this case at all. It looks like it's adding quite a bit of work, and providing little (if anything) in return.

Quite a few people are starting to advise against using `singleton`s at all, at least in C++, and quite frankly, I tend to agree most of the time. This kind of situation is why -- you usually end up with little in return for the work you do on it.

Comment: Your code won't work - you're not passing a parameter to the constructor in getInstance.

Comment: I got the point of avoiding singleton - one question on the public Constructor() though, is it still a singleton class when Connection() is called more than once?

Comment: @Oliver: Actually, you'd normally make the ctor private (which is how I've shown it, though private by default rather than explicitly specified). A singleton almost always needs the ctor private so the static `GetInstance` (or whatever) is the only way to create one.

Answer (score 1):

I've always been told to avoid singletons, so there's two parts to this:

```
class Connection {
public:
    static std::istream& getInstance() {
        assert(is);
        return *is;
    }    
    static void set_istream(std::istream & stream) {
            is = &stream;
    }
private:
    static std::istream* is;
}
std::istream* Connection::is = NULL;

int main() {
    Connection::set_istream(std::cin);
    Connection::getInstance() << "moomoomoo\n";
}
```

Note I made the stream `static`, a pointer, and global (so it's actually a singleton.  Your code.... wasn't.  There's no reason to have that many references laying around, and if you have `is = blah` where `is` is a reference, that *does not reseat the reference*.  It would copy the right to the left, which for streams, doesn't make sense and wouldn't even compile.

Of course, singletons are bad.  Use globals, or non-singletons.  (This is a global, which is only creatable once)

```
//params are ignored after first call
template<typename... Ts>
std::istream& Connection(Ts... Us) { 
    static std::ifstream c(std::forward<Ts>(Us)...);
    return c;
}

int main() {
   //construct and use
   Connect("input.txt") << "thing" << std::endl;
   Connect() << "stuff";
   Connect("this is ignored") << "IM A COW STOP SAYING IM A DUCK";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't compile for two reasons. First you have a very minor problem with the calling syntax. Fix it like this:

```
Connection::getInstance().get_input_stream();
```

Second is that you can't assign to a reference, it must be initialized at construction time. Since your constructor is called from the middle of getInstance, that's impractical. Use a pointer instead.

Yes it's awkward to need to call set_istream before your singleton is usable, but that seems unavoidable.