# Linking error for a naive singleton class in C++

Tags: c++, singleton

My code is:

```
class cMySingleton{
private:
    static bool bInstantiated;
    int mInt;
    cMySingleton(){
        mInt=0;
    }
public:
    cMySingleton(int c){
        if (bInstantiated){
            cout << "you can only instantiated once";
        }
        else {
            cMySingleton();
            mInt=c;
        }
    }
};

int main () {

    cMySingleton s(5);
    cMySingleton t(6);
}
```

The linker keeps complaining:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "cMySingleton::bInstantiated", referenced from:
      cMySingleton::cMySingleton(int) in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What is going on? C++ novice here~~

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906817/singleton-class-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should initialize static field.

http://ideone.com/Y1huV

```
#include <iostream>
class cMySingleton{
private:
    static bool bInstantiated;
    int mInt;
    cMySingleton(){
        mInt=0;
    }
public:
    cMySingleton(int c){
        if (bInstantiated){
            std::cout << "you can only instantiated once";
        }
        else {
            cMySingleton();
            mInt=c;
        }
    }
};
bool cMySingleton::bInstantiated = true;
int main () {

    cMySingleton s(5);
    cMySingleton t(6);
}
```

More information you can be find here:

[Static Data Member Initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300652/static-data-member-initialization)

there was also missing include and std:: around cout.

Comment: `bool cMySingleton::bInstantiated = 3;` really confused. Use true or false for bool initializers.

Comment: bool cMySingleton::bInstantiated = 3; nice

Answer (score 2):

Initialize

```
static bool bInstantiated;
```

outside of `cMySingleton`

```
bool CMySingleton::bInstantiated;
```

Answer (score 2):

Dont forget to initialize your static member outside of your class declaration in .cpp file:

```
bool cMySingleton::bInstantiated = false;
```